# Tile server that outputs .svg tiles instead of raster?

Tags: svg, vector-tiles, tile-server

Is there one? I found all major suppliers work with raster output (png) not vector (svg).

I wonder why.

Comment: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/19036/why-is-osm-serving-map-as-raster-instead-of-svg

Comment: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/07/20/vector-tiles-preview/

Comment: http://www.salzburgresearch.at/blog/geoserver-rendering-binary-vector-tiles/